# Backbone + jQuery Mobile - Performance-effective routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, backbone.js

I've been following a tutorial about using backbone and jqm altogether which consists of disabling the jqm router and using backbone's one instead, but i frankly dislike it's routing approach :

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes:{
    "":"home",
    "page1":"page1"
},

initialize:function () {
    // Handle back button throughout the application
    $("body").on('click', '.back', function(event) {
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    });
},

home:function () {
    console.log('#home');
    this.changePage(new HomeView());
},

page1:function () {
    console.log('#page1');
    this.changePage(new Page1View());
}

changePage:function (page) {
    $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
    page.render();
    $('body').append($(page.el));
    $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: $.mobile.defaultPageTransition, allowSamePageTransition:true});allowSamePageTransition:true});
```

What it does is that upon each hash change, it calls changePage which does a view creation, a template rendering, a div creation by appending it to the body, and a changePage to this new element.

Now, *this means creating a div on every page change*
. Also, views aren't changing everytime you change page, but only when models change, and the "render" should be fired upon model change, and the rendered view will be stored in view.el.
*What is done here is calling the render at every page show, even if the page is still the same.*

**How can I tell jqm to show the page.el with a transition, without having to do a or appending a new div to the body everytime ?**

I thought of storing my views in an array or a collection and telling the router to pull them from there, and then show it by appending a "temp div" or something, but there must be a better way.